# Countdown repeat 48H from new date Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a countdown in Javascript. I have the code now and it works fine, but I want to have more dates. So the first countdown is May 12, 2022 16:04:00, then I want a new 48h countdown from May 14, 2022 16:04:00, May 16, 2022 16:04:00 and so on. So when its May 12, 2022 16:04:01 I want a new 48h timer to start and countdown to May 14. Is this possible? Thanks for the help!

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("May 12, 2022 16:04:00").getTime();

    var x = setInterval(function () {

        var now = new Date().getTime();

        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 120 * 120 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;

        if (distance < 0) { clearInterval(x); document.getElementById("countdown-text").innerHTML = "48H"; }
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown">
                            <div class="countdown-hours">
                                <p id="hours"></p><span>hours</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="countdown-minutes">
                                <p id="minutes"></p><span>minutes</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="countdown-seconds">
                                <p id="seconds"></p><span>seconds</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: You should really get the time from the server and not the client, because client-time can be manipulated or just wrong. Then when you have a server timestamp, use it as the basepoint for the counter

Comment: How about moving you logic into a class and then you can create instances of the class with different times as you please. The constructor could for example take a `HMTLElement` which the Timer is attached to as well as a date to which to countdown to.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("May 12, 2022 16:04:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 120 * 120 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;

  if (distance < 0) {
    var numberOfMlSeconds = new Date().getTime();
    var addMlSeconds = 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    countDownDate = new Date(numberOfMlSeconds + addMlSeconds);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown">
  <div class="countdown-hours">
    <p id="hours"></p><span>hours</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-minutes">
    <p id="minutes"></p><span>minutes</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-seconds">
    <p id="seconds"></p><span>seconds</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u! This works exactly like I want!